# Does the term "ארץ ישראל" ever appear in Tanach?

Tags: tanach, words, eretz-yisrael

Do these words ever appear together as one phrase in Tanach?

Comment: Phil, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking register/login, above.

Answer (score 13):

Here is every occurrence of the phrase in Tanach:

- [Samuel I 13:19](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%92_%D7%99%D7%98)
- [Kings II 5:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%94_%D7%91)
- [Kings II 5:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%94_%D7%93)
- [Kings II 6:23](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%95_%D7%9B%D7%92)
- [Ezekiel 27:17](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%9B%D7%96_%D7%99%D7%96)
- [Ezekiel 40:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%9E_%D7%91)
- [Ezekiel 47:18](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%96_%D7%99%D7%97)
- [Chronicles I 22:2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%91)
- [Chronicles II 2:16](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%91_%D7%98%D7%96)
- [Chronicles II 30:25](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%9C_%D7%9B%D7%94)
- [Chronicles II 34:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%9C%D7%93_%D7%96)

Answer (score 9):

שמואל א: יג. יט.
וחרש לא ימצא בכל ארץ ישראל כי אמר פלשתים פן יעשו העברים חרב או חנית

מלכים ב: ה. ב.
וארם יצאו גדודים וישבו מארץ ישראל נערה קטנה ותהי לפני אשת נעמן

מלכים ב: ה. ד.
ויבא ויגד לאדניו לאמר כזאת וכזאת דברה הנערה אשר מארץ ישראל

מלכים ב: ו. כג.
ויכרה להם כרה גדולה ויאכלו וישתו וישלחם וילכו אל אדניהם ולא יספו עוד גדודי ארם לבוא 
בארץ ישראל

יחזקאל: כז. יז.
יהודה וארץ ישראל המה רכליך בחטי מנית ופנג ודבש ושמן וצרי נתנו מערבך

יחזקאל: מ. ב.
במראות אלהים הביאני אל ארץ ישראל ויניחני אל הר גבה מאד ועליו כמבנה עיר מנגב

יחזקאל: מז. יח.
ופאת קדים מבין חורן ומבין דמשק ומבין הגלעד ומבין ארץ ישראל הירדן מגבול על הים הקדמוני תמדו ואת פאת קדימה

דברי הימים א: כב. ב.
ויאמר דויד לכנוס את הגרים אשר בארץ ישראל ויעמד חצבים לחצוב אבני גזית לבנות בית האלהים

דברי הימים ב: ב. טז.
ויספר שלמה כל האנשים הגירים אשר בארץ ישראל אחרי הספר אשר ספרם דויד אביו וימצאו מאה וחמשים אלף ושלשת אלפים ושש מאות

דברי הימים ב: ל. כה.
וישמחו כל קהל יהודה והכהנים והלוים וכל הקהל הבאים מישראל והגרים הבאים מארץ ישראל והיושבים ביהודה

דברי הימים ב: לד. ז.
וינתץ את המזבחות ואת האשרים והפסלים כתת להדק וכל החמנים גדע בכל ארץ ישראל וישב לירושלם

Comment: It does seem to be in the later seforim why not in the torah itself why did we choose to call somthing it itself is not called untill later?

Comment: @whiskey, why not ask that as a separate question?

Comment: @whiskey I think the reason it is not mentioned in the Torah may be fairly "simple". The land was occupied by Cananites, Hivvites, etc. - everyone except Israelites. There doesn't seem to be a valid point to name the land "Israel" or "Eretz Yisra'el" until after, at least Joshua and B'nai Yisra'el took over. If you're wondering why the term is not mentioned in the book of Joshua, that's an excellent question. I surmise it may have a connection with having a king first which didn't occur until King Saul.