# How many times in Na"Kh is the land called Eretz Cna'an?

Tags: words, tanach, eretz-yisrael

The other side of the coin of [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5681/5) (or, if you prefer, [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5698)), might be, how often, or how many times, does the term Eretz Cna'an appear in Na"Kh after the land was given to Benei Yisrael?

Comment: Did you try searching? Or looking in a concordance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words Eretz Knaan appears 58 times in Tanach. 45 times in the Torah and 13 times in Nach.

{EDIT from @DoubleAA's [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11047/how-many-times-in-nakh-is-the-land-called-eretz-cnaan?noredirect=1#comment22453_11048)}
Of the 13 times it's in Nach, only 5 are not in the Book of Yehoshua. So the phrase only appears five times after the Jews conquer the land.

Comment: So, if we take the answers to the other questions with this one, we have the land being referred to by name a mere 16 times in all of Na"kh?

Comment: @SethJ, so it would seem. The land entire, that is. Regions of it are referred to by name also ("_od yishama b'are Y'huda_" for example).

Comment: Right. That's still interesting.

Comment: What about other names?

Comment: What about the word Cna'an appearing by itself to refer to the land (or Yisrael)?

Comment: Just to be clear to the question, of the 13 times it's in Nach, only 5 are not in the Book of Yehoshua. So the phrase only appears five times after the Jews conquer the land.